# R: transform loops into vectorized execution for correlation between rows

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vectorization, correlation

I would like conditionally select values from dt2 based on values in dt1 in a row-wise manner and then pair-wise correlate rows in dt2 and save the correlation values in a new matrix, dt3. Before I start to explain in words, I guess the R code is much more descriptive. I do this by looping over the data frame, which is quite slow. I am sure there is the possibility to do this in a vectorized manner to increase performance. Has anyone a solution or suggestion? Thank you a lot!

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(a=round(runif(100)), b=round(runif(100)), c=round(runif(100)), d=round(runif(100)), e=round(runif(100)), f=round(runif(100)))
dt2 <- data.table(a=runif(100), b=runif(100), c=runif(100), d=runif(100), e=runif(100), f=runif(100))

m <- nrow(dt2)
n <- m
dt3 <- matrix(nrow=m, ncol=n)

col_vec <- 1:n
for (r in 1:m) {
  for (p in col_vec) {
    selection <- dt1[r,] > 0 & dt1[p,] > 0 
    selection <- as.vector(selection)
    r_values <- as.numeric(dt2[p, ..selection])
    p_values <- as.numeric(dt2[r, ..selection])
    correlation_value <- cor(r_values, p_values, method='spearman', use='na.or.complete')
    dt3[r,p] <- correlation_value
    dt3[p,r] <- correlation_value
    
    print(glue('row {r} vs row {p}'))
  }
  col_vec <- col_vec[-1]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built-in `NA` exclusion mechanism with `use = "pairwise.complete.obs"`.

Set values in `dt2` as missing
if the corresponding `dt1` value is `0`, and then use one `cor()` call.

```r
library(data.table)

n <- 4
set.seed(42)

dt1 <- data.table(a = round(runif(n)), b = round(runif(n)), c = round(runif(n)), d = round(runif(n)), e = round(runif(n)), f = round(runif(n)))
dt2 <- data.table(a = runif(n), b = runif(n), c = runif(n), d = runif(n), e = runif(n), f = runif(n))

replace(t(dt2), t(dt1) == 0, NA) |>
  cor(method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]  1.0    1   -1  0.1
#> [2,]  1.0    1   NA -1.0
#> [3,] -1.0   NA    1   NA
#> [4,]  0.1   -1   NA  1.0
```

Both approaches in functions for benchmarking:

```r
f_loop <- function(dt1, dt2) {
  m <- nrow(dt2)
  n <- m
  dt3 <- matrix(nrow = m, ncol = n)

  col_vec <- 1:n
  for (r in 1:m) {
    for (p in col_vec) {
      selection <- dt1[r, ] > 0 & dt1[p, ] > 0
      selection <- as.vector(selection)
      
      r_values <- as.numeric(dt2[p, ..selection])
      p_values <- as.numeric(dt2[r, ..selection])
      
      correlation_value <- cor(r_values, p_values, method = "spearman", use = "na.or.complete")
      dt3[r, p] <- correlation_value
      dt3[p, r] <- correlation_value

      # print(glue::glue("row {r} vs row {p}"))
    }
    col_vec <- col_vec[-1]
  }

  dt3
}

f_repl <- function(dt1, dt2) {
  replace(t(dt2), t(dt1) == 0, NA) |>
    cor(method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
}
```

And test with bigger data:

```r
n <- 100
set.seed(42)

dt1 <- data.table(a = round(runif(n)), b = round(runif(n)), c = round(runif(n)), d = round(runif(n)), e = round(runif(n)), f = round(runif(n)))
dt2 <- data.table(a = runif(n), b = runif(n), c = runif(n), d = runif(n), e = runif(n), f = runif(n))

# Check that we get the same result
all.equal(f_loop(dt1, dt2), f_repl(dt1, dt2))
#> [1] TRUE

bench::system_time(f_loop(dt1, dt2))
#> process    real 
#>   5.86s   5.92s
bench::system_time(f_repl(dt1, dt2))
#> process    real 
#>   188ms   198ms
```

Comment: Just accepted it as the solution. Thank you again. Could briefly explain what the |> operator is doing?

Comment: @peter Glad to hear it worked for you! `|>` is the "forward pipe operator". Essentially, it takes the object on the left hand side and passes it as the first argument to the function on the right hand side. It's mainly useful for flattening nested calls and avoiding temporary variables. For more, see [`?pipeOp`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pipeOp.html).

Comment: I wondered how I can extend this solution to generate a second matrix of the same dimension where each value isn't specifying the correlation coefficient but instead how many values were used to perform the correlation. Do you have an idea or should I open a new question?

Comment: @peter I think that would just be `tcrossprod(dt1 != 0)`